# Plus-minus sign messes with mhchem's \pu command

Tags: bug, status-completed, mhchem

The following bug report has been fixed, [here is screenshot of the question in its original state.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grO5r.png)

---

Explicit error values are usually given as an interval with $\pm$. When I try to typeset this with mhchem's `\pu{...}` command, it sneaks some undefined markers in there and raises numbers in a funny fashion:

- $\pu{8.001 \pm 0.005 nm}$
  `\pu{8.001 \pm 0.005 nm}`
- $\pu{8.001 +/- 0.005 nm}$
  `\pu{8.001 +/- 0.005 nm}` (alternative input possibility)
  `\pu{8.001 +- 0.005 nm}` (even easier)
  `\pu{8.001+-0.005 nm}` (thinkable, lesser code readability)

I believe it should rather look like

- $8.001 \pm 0.005~\mathrm{nm}$
  `8.001 \pm 0.005~\mathrm{nm}`

Current workaround would be only typesetting the unit in the command, which kind of defeats the automatic spacing feature:

- $8.001 \pm 0.005~\pu{nm}$
  `8.001 \pm 0.005~\pu{nm}`

Similarly exponents break:

- $\pu{10^-10 m}$ `\pu{10^-10 m}`
- or worse: $\pu{7.8\times10^-10 m}$ `\pu{7.8\times10^-10 m}`
- still: $\pu{7.8\times10^{-10} m}$ `\pu{7.8\times10^{-10} m}`
- Scientific notation works though: $\pu{7.8E-10 m}$ `\pu{7.8E-10 m}`

I don't know to whether there would be other formats like this, that potentially also break. (Please leave a comment.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MathJax/mhchem 3.0.6 should fix the issues. It supports all *standard uncertaincy* notations as listed at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/58667/24052. It will take a week or so to make its way to here.

---

You can test this not-yet-released version at the bottom of https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/

Answer (score 7):

Thanks! Some of the things are already fixed on my harddrive (the "undefined" error), but not published yet. The others, I take as valid input for my todo list.

For now, `10^-10` can be written as `e-10`, but I'll support explicit exponents.

What does $8.001 \pm 0.005~\mathrm{nm}$ mean? Shouldn't it rather read $(8.001 \pm 0.005)~\mathrm{nm}$? I am not sure if I should support `\pu{7.8\times10^-10 m}`. Basically, you are asking for a `<any mathematical expression><unit>` syntax? Up to now I only had `<number><unit>` in mind. I am not sure how I could reliably differentiate between mathematical expression and unit ('$5n~\mathrm{g}$' vs. '$5~\mathrm{ng}$').

Comment: Please have a look at Loong's [answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/58667/4945). It seems like the `\pm` variations are not a good choice. However, we'll find them still quite frequently in (especially older) publications, therefore I'd think we might want to support it just for quoting purposes. Anyway, the recommended $\pu{8.001(5) nm}$ `\pu{8.001(5) nm}` is also broken.

Comment: ?? 10^-10 renders as $\ce{10^-10}$ with \ce and $10^-10$ with mathjax